# Is it a correct way in OOP programming to have a reference to interface children in its methods?

Tags: java, oop, methods, interface, default

I'm wondering if it is a good practice to use a concrete implementation of an interface (or an abstract class for that matter) in a default method? E.g.:

```
interface Foo {

    String bar();

    default Foo withPrefix(String prefix) {
        return new PrefixFooImpl(prefix, this).bar();
    }
}

// proxy class for any Foo, adding a prefix to every bar() call
class PrefixFooImpl implements Foo {

    private String prefix;
    private Foo foo;

    // constructor with Foo and prefix parameter

    public String bar() {
        return prefix + " " + foo.bar();
    }
}
```

its usage would be as follows:
instead of using

```
new PrefixFooImpl("prefix", new OtherFoo());
```

one could simply do

```
new OtherFoo().withPrefix("prefix");
```

it certainly does work, and is convenient to use, but should default interface methods contain a reference to its implementations? Isn't it a unnecessary coupling or a bad practice? And if so, is there another way to do it correctly?

Comment: Interfaces should not know about their implementations, so that's a big **no**. Why do you have to call `new PrefixFooImpl(...)`? Why not just `return prefix + " " + bar();` in `withPrefix` directly?

Comment: "Good practice" is just somebody's opinion.

Comment: @Sweeper well, it's just a simple example, `PrefixFooImpl` can have as complicated logic as one would want, and the interface is simplified as well. Taking this into account how would you approach such a problem? For example, in Scala I'd use implicit class, and the compiler would do the actual wrapping, whereas from the  client's perspective it'd look like the class implemented `bar`.

To be honest I don't like this solution, but in the code I'm working on, you are able to chain implementations of `Foo`, and wrapping them in additional `PrefixFooImpl` would just pollute the code too much

Comment: In Java, a utility class is typically provided for situations like this. You could provide a `Foos.prefix(Foo foo, String prefix)`. Similar to `List#sort`, your interface could provide `default Foo withPrefix(String prefix) { return Foos.prefix(prefix, this); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of an interface is to allow the implementation to change without affecting the callers.

In your example, the caller of `withPrefix()` may not assume that it returns `PrefixFooImpl`, they can only assume `Foo`.

Even in [supercat's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61310392/10678955), `AsImmutableEnumerable()` would not "leak" the implementation detail, which means that a change won't affect the callers.

All that, of course, is assuming that if some caller decides to cast the result of `withPrefix()` to a specific implementation, be it `PrefixFooImpl` or something else, they don't get to complain when a change occurs.

The other side, of course, is the actually allow the implementation to change.

Again with the `Foo` example, an implementation can always override `withPrefix()`, so as long as the interface is not extended with default methods, everything is still good.

If the interface is extended with default methods *after* `Foo` already has existing implementations (which won't be overriding the new methods), then the default methods need to take care to make sure the object that the caller expects still exhibits the behavior intended by the whoever instantiated the implementation (e.g. you can't return a MySQL client from an implementation of a PostgreSQL client).

In your example, the object that the caller expects proxies the original object. Other implementation may just return the original object. Those are all valid behaviors.

So, while doing these kind of things doesn't inherently violate the abstraction that the interface provides, Actually doing this strictly for syntactic convenience leads to more complicated code and more complicated debugging.

If we take the `Foo` example again, calling `withPrefix()` 10 times will crate a chain of 11 objects. Beyond the effects on GC, imagine a complex implementation of `PrefixFooImpl` - something that talks to the outside world (e.g. `DnsResolvingFooProxy` which resolves `bar` as a hostname into an IP address).

Or imagine two methods, `asIpAddress()` and `resolveLoadBalance()`, each referring to *a different implementation*.

In conclusion, it's not a violation of abstraction, but if you do use it, be very judicious about it.

Comment: calling `withPrefix()` 10 times and creating a chain of 11 objects is actually desirable in my specific case (all implementations of `Foo` are immutable, I've omitted this fact for example's brevity), but you give valid points, and I think that doing this only for syntactic convenience can indeed get out of control as the code grows.

Comment: With the introduction of default methods, I think it's pretty much accepted for interfaces to contain implementation in Java. There even exist default methods in the JCL that don't account for ALL invariants, which is typically frowned upon, but is accepted enough for production. Encapsulating implementation within objects is not frowned upon in other situations. Having the object implement `Foo` doesn't seem to matter. Unless I missed something, I'd agree what OP is doing doesn't interfere with "current practices". However, I can't help feeling there's something strange about this.

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes be a good pattern, and if the language had supported default interface implementations when interfaces like `List` and `Enumerable` were implemented, it would have made sense for them to include many more methods, most of which would be implemented using the common default implementation.

As a simple example, it would have made sense to have interface `ImmutableEnumerable` and class `ImmutableArrayList`, both of which implement `Enumerable` and guarantee that repeated enumeration will always and forevermore yield the same sequence of objects.  The `Enumerable` interface could then have included an `AsImmutableEnumerable` method whose default implementation would invoke a constructor of `ImmutableArrayList` which builds a privately-held `ArrayList` from an `Enumerable`.  The implementation of `AsImmutableEnumerable` within `ImmutableArrayList` or any other immutable collection, however, override that definition so as to simply return itself.

If code holds an `Enumerable` collection and wants to take a snapshot of it, it could call `AsImmutableEnumerable`.  If the collection is mutable, that method would copy the contents of a collection into a new immutable object, but if the collection is already immutable there would be no need to duplicate its contents.

Comment: yeah, I agree, this can be super useful and convenient, but doesn't it break a rule that abstractions shouldn't know about implementations? Or even dependency inversion principle?

Comment: @guci120: Default interface methods shouldn't assume anything about the type of object *upon which they are invoked*, but (1) they may construct instances of objects of particular classes, and exploit details of the types of objects *which they create themselves*, and (2) they may be defined for the purpose of allowing *classes which override them* to exploit their own internal details within those overrides.